# The discord.js/voice Library isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, voice

```
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, AudioPlayerStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const player = createAudioPlayer()
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    execute: async (client, msg, arg, Discord) => {
        const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return msg.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return msg.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!arg.length) return msg.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

        

     
        var connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: msg.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });
       

       
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

        }
        const keywords = await arg.join(' ')
        const video = await videoFinder(keywords);

        if (video) {
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
               
            const player = createAudioPlayer()


            var resource = createAudioResource(stream)
            player.play(resource)
      

           connection.subscribe(player);

       
         


            
           
            

           




            await msg.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        }
        else{
            msg.reply('No Results Found')
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have been looking for the solution for past some months
Even tried every platform
And went to the support server but got nothing

The codes get executed without any error
The bot joins the VC also sends a message that playing your song

But in the VC the bot doesn't speak anything

So someone can please help me
To solve the code or fixed something which I need to
Note: I have installed each required dependencies

Comment: please add a debug log to your question 
```client.on("debug", e => console.log(e))``` so we can see if it is actually sending the stream bits.

Comment: This isn't working for me either, on the latest version of discord.js (13.x). Downgrading to version 12.x had this work as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const voice = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    execute: async (client, msg, arg, Discord) => {
        const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return msg.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return msg.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!arg.length) return msg.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

        const connection = voice.joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: msg.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });
        try{
            await voice.entersState(connection, voice.VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 30e3);
        } catch(error) {
            connection.destroy();
            return console.error(error);
        }

    
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

        }
        const keywords = await arg.join(' ')
        const video = await videoFinder(keywords);

        if (video) {
            const videoinfo = await ytdl.getInfo(video.url);
            try{
                var stream = await ytdl.downloadFromInfo(videoinfo);
            } catch (error){
                msg.reply(`Error while creating stream`);
                return console.error(error);
            }
            
            const player = voice.createAudioPlayer()


            const resource = voice.createAudioResource(stream, {
                inputType: voice.StreamType.Arbitrary,
                inlineVolume: true
            });

            player.play(resource);
            voice.entersState(player, voice.AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, 5e3);
    

            connection.subscribe(player);

            player.on('subscribe', async () => {
                await msg.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`);
            });
        } else{
            msg.reply('No Results Found')
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: @AryanGagare have you enabled the 'GUILD_VOICE_STATES' intent in the Discord.js client? That was something I always forgot.

Comment: I have made the intent as 32767

Comment: @AryanGagare You'll need to specify your intents in your client. In the index it will look like ```new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES]})```